# fluentd gelf plugin parameters setting

Tags: kubernetes-helm, fluentd, graylog, gelf

Can someone explain me what each of this means? I tried a lot of search on google but can't get to it. These values are populated in my helmfile dry-run in configmap but I need to know what they are.

I am interested in know each of these as to what they imply?

```
buffer_chunk_limit 4096K
buffer_queue_limit 512
flush_interval 5s
max_retry_wait 30
disable_retry_limit
num_threads 4
```

```
helmfile --file=helmfile.yaml --selector name=fluentd-team sync --args "--debug --namespace=monitor --dry-run"
```

```
<match **>
      @type gelf
      host graylog-ingestion.monitor.company.com
      port 122
      protocol tcp
      tls true
      buffer_chunk_limit 4096K
      buffer_queue_limit 512
      flush_interval 5s
      max_retry_wait 30
      disable_retry_limit
      num_threads 4
</match>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are fluentd [Buffered Output Parameters](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/output#buffered-output-parameters)